# Where do I find API docs for Angular CDK Collections SelectionModel?

Tags: angular-cdk

I expected to find something about `SelectionModel` in [the Angular CDK docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories), but keep coming up short.

There are many API pages; for example, [Angular Components docs for MatTable](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api). Yes, [the code for `SelectionModel`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/collections/selection-model.ts) is on **GitHub**, but I would like to:

1. read the an overview" like the many such pages on **angular.io* while also
2. learning from examples like those on **angular.io** or from third-parties, and
3. reading the code.

What I seem to be missing is #1, but only for certain classes.

Some other non-component classes are documented at **angular.io**.  [MatTableDataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource)  can be found in right-hand column of the [MatTable API documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api).  Okay, that's not exactly obvious, but it is a useful location.  I might have expected to find collections somewhere like [CDK Collections page](https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories/component-composition), but alas it is not there.

1. Is **angular.io** the official location for such stuff?
2. Have I missed a way to find API documentation for `SelectionModel`
   class and maybe other classes in `cdk\collection` or am I really just reporting a website bug?

Answer (score 3):

I **THINK** that this is another case of Google's lacklustre attitude towards documentation. Time and time again I come across situations where their docs are either incorrect, out-of-date or missing entirely. This is not specific to Angular, but to any of their products.

Yes, to the largest part the Angular docs are fantastic. The Material docs, however, often have holes like this and are inconsistent at times.

I don't think you're missing anything, Paul.

I know this is a year "late". I had the same question now and stumbled upon this unanswered reflection of my frustrations :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to commiserate with me.
The only bite directed me to a github page called `collections.md`, but surprisingly contains a non-use case example calling of a 'SelectionModel`  Why this responder thought to look there is a mystery to me, and also why I'd look to a github repo with little indication how it correspond to the current release. 

Clicking on  `Components` scrolling down 5 pages, there is actually a link to ang. mat io, but only to the landing page. Good luck nav'ing to an example which uses a `SelectionModel`

Comment: When all was said and done, I ended up not using `SelectionModel`, I put info about what was selected in my app. data model maintained in an Angular Service, because selections were very important to what the app was calculating/doing, so having something only in the UI component that knows selections corresponding to one list/collection was actually not useful.  

Having selection info in a service allowed more than one screen in the UI to change a selection, display what was selected, display a summary of what was selected in different lists or simply show totals etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is document page

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/collections/collections.md

The collections package provides a set of utilities for managing collections.

SelectionModel
SelectionModel is a utility for powering selection of one or more options from a list. This model is used in components such as the selection list, table selections and chip lists.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I asked 2 questions, but you answered neither.

I can read the newest code, but I don't want the newest, I want the docs which match the module in my project.  How would I know the relation between some coders check in a few days ago and the current code I am using?  Where is that documented?

At [github.com/angular/components](https://github.com/angular/components) readme.md has a DOCS link for a component and all go to **angular.io**  which has a dropdown for which version of the modules, but there is still no SelectionModel. 
Anyone know why?